# C++ char*[255] producing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I know this is probably something basic that has been talked about 1000 times, but I think I need help understanding why the following produces a segmentation fault:

```
char* outputPath = new char[255];
sprintf(outputPath, "/home/istrab/iStrabGUI Output/%s/%s/0/Frames",patientName, techName);
```

The reason I wonder this is because after some research I've declared the size of the array to be 255, which I know would be large enough to hold the string I wish to write to it.  I also made sure it was initialized before I tried to write to it.  I also made doubly sure that any involved variables were initialized earlier in the code or the program would have exited by then.  Is there another way I could be going about this?  Is it in the string itself or the way I initialized the array?

This code was written using Qt 4.8.6 in C++

Comment: Why not use a string object instead of a char array? Would save you a lot of headache.

Comment: `char outputPath[255]` would be more idiomatic IMO. Also there are constants/defines for a maximum path length you should use (for portability if nothing else)

Comment: Stop violating the [zero one infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) already.

Comment: Most likely answer, `patientName` or `techName` are malformed or longer than you expect, overflowing the allocated memory. Second most likedly, you could allocate the memory for `outputPath` because you never free it and ran out of memory.

Comment: This is supposed to be C++, right?  `std::ostringstream strm; strm << "/home/istrab/iStrabGUI Output/" << patientName << '/' << techName << "/0/Frames";  std::string outputPath = strm.str();` -- Even if techname or patientName go haywire and are larger than expected, the code still works.

Comment: *The reason I wonder this is because after some research I've declared the size of the array to be 255,* -- Don't write programs using this way of thinking, and especially don't write ones where you have no way of *ensuring* these preconditions hold.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) needed. Also, reading about [how to ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) might be a good idea.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you should not use `sprintf`, use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) instead (though you should use just a `std::string` but maybe you have your limitations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QString` if If you are using Qt anyway:

```
QString outputPath;
outputPath.sprintf( "/home/istrab/iStrabGUI Output/%s/%s/0/Frames",
                    patientName, 
                    techName);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this method and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Run gdb on it and put a break on that line, then print the value of patientName and techName.  One of the two is probably null.

Comment: I know that they are not, because I used print commands to print them before the offending line is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QDir` methods.

```
QDir path("/home/istrab/iStrabGUI Output/");
path.cd(patientName);
path.cd(techName);
path.cd("/0/Frames");

QString pathString = path.path();
```

Answer (score 0):

The vars patientName, techName are the problem, you should use resize outputPath to become bigger and won't be overflowed.

But I try to figure out to use a string var from string library. 
[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193173/getting-cout-output-to-a-stdstring)